# Auto-hiding Launcher stopped working

Tags: dual-boot, unity, 16.04, mac

EDIT: I know how set the launcher to hide, and yes, I set to auto-hide.

The Launcher on Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't hiding... I set into behavior setting Auto-Hide ON, but after some times it stopping to hide...

I installed Ubuntu on my Mac Book Pro...

To fix it I run: `setsid unity`, but exist a better solution??

EDIT
Result of `sudo lshw | grep -A9 VGA`:

```
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GK107M [GeForce GT 650M Mac Edition]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
--
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

Comment: FYI, the proper terminology is Launcher.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include further information that might shed some light on your problem. `sudo lshw | grep -A9 VGA` might be helpful.

Comment: @Zacharee1 But did you read my question?? It is different from that

Comment: I do not fully understand the problem -- does the launcher auto-hide for a while, but then gets stuck in the visible position?  This happens to me occasionally, and is quickly remedied with a four-finger swipe left on the trackpad.

Comment: @wutangforever yes, I discover that too.. But if I disable "Tap To Click" I can't swipe it.. And then I think isn't the right behaviour